# Angular2 Router : Regex Parameters like angular-ui-router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there a simpler way to define route similar to following in Angular 2

```
'/files/{path:.*}' - Matches any URL starting with '/files/' and    
captures the rest of the path into the parameter 'path'.
OR
'/files/*path'

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing
```

I looked at following Angular2 issue and urlMatcher solution in that, but that seems too much for reading rest of the path as a parameter.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12442